# Why is scroll not considering padding

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `padding: 20px;` and `overflow: auto;`, (green area), which contains a table. Both elements are set to `box-sizing: border-box`.

[image]

Why is it that the overflow on the right side is not showing the scroll bar? As soon as the content of the `div` (the table) exceeds the green area, the scroll bar appears, like there was no actual padding.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: using css you can solve this issue simply with `table{ width: calc(100% - 40px)}` . Or you can also try to set `table { width: 100%; max-width : 100% } `

Comment: try using margin instead of padding!

Comment: @adel same issue

Comment: provide a more detailed code so we  can help you better!

Comment: I just wanted to find a solution to this issue, without a workout - my question was just concerning why this issue is occuring and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the overflow is related to the width and height of the parent container. The padding inside does not count as overflow as the width or height of the element is not exceeded. Once the child is outside the boundaries of the parent it counts as overflow.

To create the behaviour you want you want wrap a `div` around the `table` inside the padded `div` and set the `overflow` property to the new `div`.

Example:

```
.padded {
    padding: 20px;
}

.overflowing {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```
<div class="padded">
    <div class="overflowing">
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good solution, thank you! However it's not compatible as how I want it to work.

Comment: You are welcome. If this does not answer your question then please state what the desired result is in your initial question.

Comment: My question was just concerning why this issue is occuring and how to fix it.

Comment: Well, your table seems to be larger than your div. So it stretches beyond the div' padding. Tables are notoriously hard to scale responsively. Some consensus should be made somewhere. Although if you implement the example I've provided above the table should stay inside the `20px` padding of the outer container and only overflow in the inner div. And that keeps the scrollbar within the `20px` padding limit.